# how to enter dates in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I'm trying to create a table to import data from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/sulianova/cardiovascular-disease-dataset) using SQL Shell. I'm having problems with the date import. 
I've altered the date to the correct format yyyy-mm-dd in excel and save it as .csv but when I try to copy in the data (using https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/ as a guide) its recognising it as an integer. How can I overcome this?
I know I can enter a date in inverted commas but I cant do that manually for 70K entries.

Comment: Have you examined the csv file to confirm the dates have been exported with the desired format? Often tools like excel only change the *rendering* of the format you see, but internally and when exporting leave it as the parochial american format

Comment: I subsequently opened the file in notepad and the format looked correct.

Comment: Please copy-paste a couple of first lines of the csv from notepad (before and after Excel mutilation), your CREATE TABLE command and the COPY command you use.

Comment: The site you are reading your data from seems to offer age (probably on the date of measurement) in days, not a birth date nor date of measurement. Please check what your data is before you have made any modifications to it.

Comment: This worked (although I dont think birthdate is correct as age is in days in raw data). create table.
CREATE TABLE patient_data (id INT, age DATE, gender INT, height INT, weight INT, ap_hi INT, ap_lo INT, cholesterol INT, gluc INT, smoke BOOL, alco BOOL, active BOOL, cardio BOOl);
Copy.
COPY patient_data FROM 'C:\kaggledata/cardio_train1.csv'DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

Comment: before excel
id;age;gender;height;weight;ap_hi;ap_lo;cholesterol;gluc;smoke;alco;active;cardio
0;18393;2;168;62.0;110;80;1;1;0;0;1;0
1;20228;1;156;85.0;140;90;3;1;0;0;1;1

after excel
id,age,gender,height,weight,ap_hi,ap_lo,cholesterol,gluc,smoke,alco,active,cardio
0,1950-05-10,2,168,62,110,80,1,1,0,0,1,0
1,1955-05-19,1,156,85,140,90,3,1,0,0,1,1

Answer (score 0):

I usually have this 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ' and it works pretty fine for timestamp. Be careful with the 24H and 12H format.

[image]